# SQL Server cannot show apostrophe (') when database is restored

Tags: sql-server

I restore the database and then select the rows. Apostrophe (`'`) cannot show correctly.
The data type of column is `varchar`.

The actual text is

```
CM's Approval - Payment of Legal
```

But it is shown like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5_HcIY4BUJmWFRfTkR0bm5QOFE/view?usp=sharing

Any suggestion please.

Comment: The link gives me an 403 error. Could you upload the captured image to imgur or something like that please?

Comment: Sounds like a charset/encoding issue.

Comment: Sorry guy, I have updated my captured image link.